# UIButton Enabled and Alpha not updating

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am currently enabling and disabling buttons on a UIViewController. I find that the first time I change their enabled state they respond, but following on from that the buttons will enable or disable but their appearance on the form does not update.

This means that after I call my method the buttons enable but their appearance does not change.

I was doing this without the alpha bit but I was getting the same problem. I tried adding the code for alpha as a work around but without any joy.

Any help is appreciated.

```
-(void)enableValidButtons
{
serverAuthentication *login = [serverAuthentication sharedServerAuthentication];

BOOL enabled =login.userAuthenticated;
float alpha;
if (enabled){
    alpha = 1.0;
}else{
    alpha = 0.5;
}

_shiftLogButton.enabled = enabled;
_shiftLogButton.alpha = alpha;
_scanButton.enabled = enabled;
_scanButton.alpha = alpha;
_rebuildButton.enabled = enabled;
_rebuildButton.alpha = alpha;

[self.view layoutSubviews];
}
```

Comment: How do you create the buttons? How did you verify that they are disabled?

Comment: What exactly is `login.userAuthenticated` returning?

Comment: Make sure you are on mainThread [NSThread isMainThread], otherwise dispatch the alpha value changes by calling dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^blockWithAlphaChanges);

Comment: The buttons are created on the storyboard. login.userAuthenticated is a method that returns true if the current user has been authenticated with a remote server. I have tried changing the alpha in the main queue without any change.